# How to calculate what entity is drawn first (2D java rendering using Slick2D)

Tags: java

### **Explanation:**

**EDIT3: MASSIVE CLEAN UP as this was not clearly explained.**

I'm trying to build up a 2D level out of tiles and entities. Where the entities are **for example** trees that can be cut. I need to store the data (how many chops are left for example) for each entity. I want them to have a more dynamic position (doubles) and a more dynamic sprite-width and height. My tiles are 32x32 pixels whilst my trees are not going to be one tile but a sprite with greater height than width.

I want objects that are closer to the top of the level to be drawn before the other objects. In this case a character behind the tree will cannot be rendered in or in front of the tree. This case also applies to other objects of the same kind (like trees).
I think it might be too inefficient to loop through the entities and calculate each entity's  position since there may be a LOT of entites in the level.

As I've done some research I found that certain libraries allow the storage of both the object and it's position in a MAP (BiMap in google's Guava).

### **Questions:**

- Is this an inefficient manner.. but are there some changes that can
  be applied to make the rendering more efficient (if so, what could be
  optimized)?
- Or is this an inefficient manner to render the entities    and is
  there a better way (if so, what other methods are there in    Java)?
- Or is there something else that I haven't listed?

**EDIT2:** I looked through the link I've posted in the edit below.
It seems that Google's Guava (I think that's all correct) has BiMaps. Is there an equivalent to this in regular Java? Otherwise Google's Library will probably be able to fix this for me. But I'd rather not install such a huge library for this one interface.

### **At last:**

It's very much possible that the answer has been right in front of my nose here on StackOverflow or somewhere else on the internet. I've tried my best searching but found nothing.
If you've got any suggestions for search queries or any relevant links that might be of use to me I would appriciate it if you'd post them in the comments.

Thanks for taking the time to read through this/helping me ;)

### **EDIT:**

I have looked at; [Efficient mapping of game entity positions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027538/efficient-mapping-of-game-entity-positions-in-java?rq=1) .
I think it's narrowly related to this question. But I think it's just not what I'm looking for. I am going to look through the second answer very closely since that might be able to solve this for me.. but I'm not sure.

## **SOLUTION**

The solution is to have an array, arraylist or another manner to keep track of your entities. Every tick/update you'll take all the object's Y coordinates and store them in another array/arraylist/map/other with the same size as where the entities are stored in. On every equivalent position to the entity you'll store it's Y. Then you'll order it with another loop or using http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html .

Then when rendering:

```
for(int i = 0; i < entityArray.length; i++)
entityArray[i].render();
```

Off course you'll render it more efficiently by rendering only whats on or near your screen.
But that's basically how one does this in 2D top-view/front-view.

Comment: Oh yeah; To everyone reading this with the same problem later on: Look at the main post. The solution should be there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own 2d game attempts I come up with the following solution:

- use an enum to specify different types of objects in game and give them priorities (sample order: grass, rivers, trees, critters, characters, clouds, birds, GUI)
- make all visual objects implement interface which allows for getting this DrawPriority enum
- use a sorted implementation of list with comparator based on the enum
- use the list to draw all elements

That way the order computing is not very expensive, because it is done only on Visual Object insertion (which is in my case done while loading a level).

.. And since you will already using a comparator, do a x/y comparison when the enum priority values are the same. This should solve your y-order draw problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm searching for. It's very useful though, and I'll keep it in mind for later (thanks! ;D).
Let's say that I have 2 clouds. (Which have the same ENUM value.)
In this case I want the cloud that's closer to (0.0, 0.0) (that being coordinates) to be drawn first, and clouds closer the the bottom-right of the lever to be drawn last. In this case a person for example can stand in front of the tree or behind the tree. But if the person is closer to the top of the level than the tree it'll be drawn first instead of being drawn in the tree.

Comment: @JoannisO added a note about extending the comparator to take y coordinate into account

Comment: Except for the ENUMs (which I'm really grateful, thanks!) that was the inefficient method to me. As I've edited the original post 3 times now  I think it might be clearer now. I've also added more information on what I found closely related as I've already searched. I've got one more question in response to this: Would it be more efficient to store entities in a "regular" manner and loop through them to compare the Y axis all the time (keep in mind, I could store a map of which entities get drawn first). Or is it more efficient to store their coordinates next to their object?

Comment: Did you actually try it? Did you profile your app? If not, then do not worry right now. If so: do your objects often change their location? If not, then my method should be efficient. Sort for a nearly-ordered list should be near-O(n) complexity. I doubt that it will be a problem for you.

Comment: I think I've got it. I've found 2 pages somewhere using google earlier today. I'll post the solution in the original post. Thanks for helping me this well since it's my first question on StackOverflow. So I don't really know how to properly manage a question like this. Using your method combined with one or two native Java API methods I could do this pretty efficiently.